# Upgrade material ui project from v0.20 to v1

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, upgrade

it's mandatory for our project to upgrade our material ui version at least initially to version 1. Our project scaled up and the current version makes us problems. Our current version is `v0.20.2` It's really old as you can see haha
I follow the `https://material-ui.com/guides/migration-v0x/` but the following error occurs:

```
    Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See httpsinvalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
    at resolveDispatcher (react.development.js:1590)
    at useMemo (react.development.js:1642)
    at Provider (Provider.js:10)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:8032)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:8221)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:10224)
    at workLoop (react-dom.development.js:10288)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:542)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:581)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:438)
```

My package.json is this:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/codemod": "^4.5.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "^1.0.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.5.1",
    "@material-ui/styles": "^4.8.2",
    "babel-polyfill": "~6.22.0",
    "browser-filesaver": "~1.1.1",
    "build-url": "~1.2.0",
    "es6-promise": "~4.2.5",
    "file-saver": "~2.0.1",
    "iban": "~0.0.8",
    "immutable": "~3.8.2",
    "jsdoc": "^3.6.3",
    "jsdoc-api": "~3.0.0",
    "loaders.css": "~0.1.2",
    "material-ui": "^0.20.2",
    "moment": "~2.20.1",
    "prop-types": "~15.6.0",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-datepicker": "~0.48.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.1",
    "react-feature-toggles": "~3.0.3",
    "react-intl": "~2.4.0",
    "react-loaders": "~3.0.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.3",
    "react-router": "~3.2.0",
    "react-tooltip": "~3.10.0",
    "redux": "~3.7.2",
    "redux-form": "~8.1.0",
    "redux-form-material-ui": "~4.3.3",
    "redux-immutable": "~4.0.0",
    "redux-persist": "~4.8.0",
    "redux-persist-immutable": "~4.3.1",
    "redux-saga": "~0.15.3",
    "whatwg-fetch": "~2.0.1"
  },
```

Has anyone upgrade to material ui v1 from 0.20.2 successfully? And if so which are the
exact steps you've followed?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show your `package.json`. Was there any stacktrace included with that error? Do you know what code it was trying to execute?

Comment: check my package json thanks!

Comment: Please answer the other questions (any stacktrace? what was being executed when the error occurred?).

Comment: Check the updated answer )

Answer (score 1):

You have different versions of `react` and `react-dom`. The `react-dom` version you are using (16.2.1) doesn’t support hooks. You should change it to be the same as your `react` version (16.12.0).

Comment: Hey now i've got this error Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `LoginPage`.
    at createFiberFromTypeAndProps (react-dom.development.js:26629)

Comment: the loginPage is exported

Comment: Please create a new question with the stack trace and relevant code of the new error.

Comment: My guess (without seeing the code) is that you have a bad import statement.